How to add app permissions for Android app
I would like to submit an app to the Play Store, but I am a tad bit confused as far as permissions are concerned.
Basically, the app would need permission for the users to either take pictures (Camera usage) or upload from their gallery (I believe that is the Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE? I don’t know if that is the correct term for accessing their gallery and such.
Do I just declare something like this in the AndroidManifest file? And is that all it would take, please? Or it should be declared elsewhere, and how if so, please?

<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <application ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>


It's explained in the docs. Manifest declaration is one thing, but you also need to implement code to actually query those (dangerous) permissions during runtime of your app.

And the docs.

Wow. I see. I have to learn more about it then.

You will have to add both Camera and External Storage permission like this in AndroidManifest.xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

And the following way to check runtime permissions in code
    val requestMultiplePermissions = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()
) { permissions ->
    permissions.entries.forEach {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "${it.key} = ${it.value}")
    }
}

requestMultiplePermissions.launch(
    arrayOf(
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    )
)

